# Transparent Status bar in Specific Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-statusbar

In my application there is an activity which contains four fragments. I want to make transparent specific one fragment out of four fragments.
Home fragment is alright as I want however the status bar is also disappear for other fragments which I don't want. I would like to show the statusbar for other 3 three fragments.

```
private void transparentStatusBar() {
    Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a function like this one in your activity and call it from the fragments that you need

```
fun transparentStatusBar(transparent: Boolean) {
    if (transparent) {
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    } else {
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, true)
        window.statusBarColor = ColorHelper.resolveColorAttribute(this, R.attr.statusBarBackground)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set the transparent status bar it's always in refence to activity , so in this all fragments in that activity will have transparent status bar.
In this scenario, you can set and remove transparent status bar as you switch from or to your desired transparent status bar fragment.

Comment: a sample code or reference would help everyone instead.